# Advanced split tunnel question

Tags: cisco-asa, vpn

We are in a work from home state, and I am looking at optimizing VPN without sacrificing security. We are not using split tunnel.

We have Direct Access on most clients - it is slow, and have moved some over to AnyConnect where we 
On company network we are using a proxy server and TMG firewall client (default route just drops Internet bound traffic with few whitelisted exceptions)

We have blocked YouTube, Netflix and other bandwidth hogs.

Is there any way we can:
1. Send traffic to Symantec WSS directly (no tunnel) - Say 8 subnets to get good coverage of data centers
2. Send 10.0.0.0/8 over DA / AnyConenct
3. Blackhole (prefered) or route over VPN tunnel remaining traffic.

So basicly, push routes out, determining if they are local or tunnel.

Right now with AnyConnect, I have the routes below:
So a default route running over VPN with low metric, and another with high metric using local breakout.
So adding local routes out would help a lot, then we can filter default route on company network. Seems like most split tunnel lets you specify tunnel routes only, not the local routes.

```
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.1.1    192.168.1.172     35
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0       10.1.200.1      10.1.200.46      2
       10.1.200.0    255.255.252.0         On-link       10.1.200.46    257
...
```

Direct Access is different, it keeps my IP4 gateway, as only default IPv4 gateway. So I can access everything local (192.168.1.0/24). So must route the rest through IP6 tunnel (over IPv4).

Comment: Found it. ACE aka Access Control Entry in policy should allow me to do that.
Now just need Direct Access solution

Comment: You should answer your own question so that others can benefit from your experience.

Comment: Sure. But I need our operations partner to implement it, so I can test and report back. We have other pressing issues due to 50x more users working from home